# <body> goes down as I put style to Bootstrap nav { position:fixed }

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am using Bootstrap Scrollspy. I added one Bootstrap nav (class = "nav nav-pills nav-stackedon") on left side of page and  was on right side. First problem was that nav becomes invisible as I scroll down, so I added style to it:

```
.my-navbar {
position:fixed;
}
```

Then everything was fine with navbar (it became fixed to top), but the problem is that the body is now below navbar instead of being on right side of it. Why is that so and how to correct it?

My view is here:

```
@model Questionnaire.Domain.Models.StudentVM
@using System.Linq
@using System.Collections.Generic
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Student";
}

@{
    List<String> subjectNames = new List<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Subjects.Count; i++)
    {
        subjectNames.Add(Model.Subjects[i].Name);
    }
}
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".my-navbar">
    <div class="row panel">
        <div class="my-navbar col-xs-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#opsta">Opšta pitanja</a></li>
                @for (int i = 1; i < subjectNames.Count; i++)
                {
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" onclick="onClickHandle(@subjectNames[i])">@subjectNames[i]</a></li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <span id="opsta"></span>
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Subjects.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="well well-outside">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Subjects[i].ID)
                        <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Subjects[i].Name)</h3>
                        @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Subjects[i].Questions.Count; j++)
                        {
                            <div class="well well-inside">
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Subjects[i].Questions[j].ID)
                                <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Subjects[i].Questions[j].Text)</h3>
                                @foreach (var answer in Model.Subjects[i].Questions[j].PossibleAnswers)
                                {
                                    <div>
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Subjects[i].Questions[j].SelectedAnswer, answer.ID, new { id = answer.ID })
                                        <label for="@answer.ID">@answer.Text</label>
                                    </div>
                                }
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Subjects[i].Questions[j].SelectedAnswer)
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                }
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Confirm" />
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The body is below the navbar because you have set the style to be fixed. It is quite difficult to help with this without seeing all the styling dependencies. But try to remove position fixed and say float:left;

Comment: float:left doesn't make it stay on the page while scrolling :(

Comment: setting `position:fixed` removes the nav bar from the regular flow of the page, so the page acts like nothing is there in its place. You can either style the rest of the page to act as if it is there (margin, padding, other) or put an empty container in its place with similar dimension, just no content.

Comment: @lemieuxster, yep, I added margin-left to body. Thank you. You can answer the question if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting `position:fixed` removes the nav bar from the regular flow of the page, so the page acts like nothing is there in its place. You can either style the rest of the page to act as if it is there (margin, padding, other) or put an empty container in its place with similar dimension, just no content.